# Private Beta follow link message craziness on Area 51

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51

Just spotted this bug on Area 51 [Linguistics overview page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6673/linguistics):

[image]

Comment: Ew, and it's wrapped in a `<b>` tag. :(

Comment: I think it's Area51's way of letting you know that you need to spend more time [gardening](http://gardening.stackexchange.com) (_hint hint wink wink_) :D

Comment: @yoda - OMG it's the gardening SE mafia! You can check my last seen date - it says 4 secs. Just don't put a horse head in my garden bed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oops! It's fixed now. Thank you.